# HttpContext: user identity is empty when running on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've ran into a very interesting problem. I'm trying to authenticate the user by his AD username if no username has been put in in another way.

For thise I'm using the following method. The interesting thing is, when I run it locally from visual studio it works as intended. On the other hand if I run it on the server the username is always empty (thus "non authenticated"). The server itself though is in the same domain as me. Thus I'm not sure whre the thinking error could be at.

```
private Tuple<bool, string> AuthenticateUser(string userName, System.Web.HttpContext httpContext)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)
        && httpContext != null && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Replace("MYDomain", "").Replace("\\", "");
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
    {
        _UserName = userName;

        return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, userName);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, string>(false, String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Thus what is wrong here? (Page itself is an `aspx` page).

Comment: What authentication/identity have you enabled in iis manager for this web site? Post a picture of your setup (eg this page https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/adminstudio2015sp1/Content/ashelplibrary/WFMAuthentication.png) remember to check the config of your remote server not the config of your local server

Comment: Did you set it up on IIS? You have to configure it to enable authentication (like window authentication ...)

Comment: Are the authentication methods you have enabled locally the same on the server?

Comment: That will be the problem prolly @CaiusJard  . I used the default configs both locally and on the remote server. Taht is then windows authentification if I'm correct (in the authentication menu)